# getting the value of a check box

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-6

Ok, I am running a javascript that is testing a bunch of  to see if they are changed, and if they are changed, I need to see if a check box is checked.  I am not using a form to do this, however, for certain reasons.  Here is the code for the display of the table:

```
<table class="db-view-sku-table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Merge <br />Callouts</th>
        <th>Current Page</th>
        <th>Current Callout</th>
        <th>New Page</th>
        <th>New Callout</th>
        <th>MFG SKU</th>
        <th>Client SKU</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="odd changed_value">
      <td class="hidden db-sku-nid">192297</td>
      <td class="hidden db-co-nid">212300</td>
      <td class="merge"><input type="checkbox" name = "mergeme" class="checked" /></td>
      <td class="db-current-page"><a href="/node/212299" target="_blank">6</a></td>
      <td class="db-current-co">A</td>
      <td class="db-move-page"><input type="text" class="page-select" size="4" value="" /></td>
      <td class="db-move-co"><input type="text" class="co-select" size="4" value="A" /></td>
      <td class="db-sku"><a href="/plain/node/192297/edit" class="popup" title="Click to view global SKU details in popup window.">AAG794200</a></td>
      <td class="db-client-sku editable-text">AAG-794200</td>
      <td class="db-description">AT-A-GLANCE Sorbet Wkl/Mthly Plnr</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even changed_value">
      <td class="hidden db-sku-nid">97160</td>
      <td class="hidden db-co-nid">212301</td>
      <td class="merge"><input type="checkbox" name = "mergeme" class="checked" /></td>
      <td class="db-current-page"><a href="/node/212299" target="_blank">6</a></td>
      <td class="db-current-co">A</td>
      <td class="db-move-page"><input type="text" class="page-select" size="4" value="" /></td>
      <td class="db-move-co"><input type="text" class="co-select" size="4" value="A" /></td>
      <td class="db-sku"><a href="/plain/node/97160/edit" class="popup" title="Click to view global SKU details in popup window.">AAG76PN0105</a></td>
      <td class="db-client-sku editable-text">AAG-76PN0105</td>
      <td class="db-description">QUICKNOTES WKLY/MNTH, SPECIAL EDITION</td>
```

Code when save button is pushed:

```
function setupMassSave() {
$('.save-button').click(function() {
    var merge = getMergeList();
    var skus = getSkuList();
    var pages = getPageList();
    var callouts = getCalloutList();
    var currco = getCurrCalloutList();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/skumove/save_all/' + merge + '/' + skus + '/' + pages + '/' + callouts + '/' + currco,
        cache: false,
        success: refreshView
    });
});
}

function getSkuList() {
var slist = [];
$('.changed_value').each(function(index) {
    if(!$(this).children('.merge').children('.checked').checked){ 
        slist.push($(this).children('.db-sku-nid').text());
    }
});
return slist;
}
function getMergeList() {
var mlist = [];
$('.changed_value').each(function(index) {
    if($(this).children('.merge').children('.checked').checked) { 
        mlist.push($(this).children('.db-sku-nid').text());
    }
});
return mlist;
}
```

The only ones I'm having a problem with are those two functions.  They other 3 functions work fine and return the values I need.  I know the problem is somewhere within the ('.merge').clicked area.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.checked` is a (Boolean) vanilla JavaScript property, which you're trying to apply to a jQuery object. That's why it's not working.

Replace

```
$(this).children('.merge').children('.checked').checked
```

with either

```
$(this).children('.merge').children('.checked')[0].checked
```

or

```
$(this).children('.merge').children('.checked').is(':checked')
```

or

```
$(this).children('.merge').children('.checked:checked').length
```

Comment: I used the following:      if($(this).children('.merge').children('.checked').is(':checked')){

Answer (score 1):

use the pseudo selector :checked instead of the class selector .checked

```
if($(this).children('.merge').children(':checked').length) { 
    mlist.push($(this).children('.db-sku-nid').text());
}
```